# ASP.NET CORE EF Specified cast is not valid

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Disculpen no entiendo porque no me deja listar mi modelo, tengo esta imagen con el error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

public IEnumerable GetBalanzas()
        {
            var listado = new List();

```
        using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())

        {

            var query = db.Balanza;

            listado = query.ToList();
        }

        return listado;
    }
```

Mi modelo es este

```
 public class Balanza
   {
    [Key]
    public int BalanzaID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Codigo de Balanza:")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe ingresar el codigo de la Balanza")]
    [MaxLength(20, ErrorMessage = "El campo no debe exceder 20 caracteres")]
    public string Cod_Balanza { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Marca:")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe ingresar la marca")]
    [MaxLength(20, ErrorMessage = "El campo no debe exceder 20 caracteres")]
    public string Marca { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Serie:")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe ingresar la serie")]
    [MaxLength(20, ErrorMessage = "El campo no debe exceder 20 caracteres")]
    public string Serie { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Fabrica:")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe ingresar la fabrica")]
    [MaxLength(20, ErrorMessage = "El campo no debe exceder 20 caracteres")]
    public string Fabrica { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Modelo:")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe ingresar la modelo")]
    [MaxLength(20, ErrorMessage = "El campo no debe exceder 20 caracteres")]
    public string Modelo { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Descripcion de Balanza:")]
    [MaxLength(150, ErrorMessage = "El campo no debe exceder 150 
   caracteres")]
    public string Des_balanza { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Tipo de Balanza(1:manual,2:automática):")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe escoger el tipo de balanza")]
    public char Tip_balanza { get; set; } //1:manual, 2:automatica
    [Display(Name = "Tipo de Situación de 
   balanza(1:propio,2:alquilado,3:ajeno):")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe escoger el situación de la balanza")]
    public char Sit_balanza { get; set; }//1:propio,2:alquilado,3:ajeno
    [Display(Name = "Propietario de la balanza:")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe ingresar el propietario de la balanza")]
    [MaxLength(20, ErrorMessage = "El campo no debe exceder 20 caracteres")]
    public string Pro_balanza { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Capacidad máxima:")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe ingresar la capacidad máxima")]
    [Range(0, 9999999, ErrorMessage = "Íncorrecto, no puede ser menor que 
    0.")]
    public decimal Cap_maxima { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Capacidad mínima:")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe ingresar la capacidad mínima")]
    [Range(0, 9999999, ErrorMessage = "Íncorrecto, no puede ser menor que 
     0.")]
    public decimal Cap_minima { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Ubicación:")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe ingresar la ubicación")]
    [MaxLength(20, ErrorMessage = "El campo no debe exceder 20 caracteres")]
    public string ubicacion { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Fecha de Fabricación:")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe ingresar la Fecha de Fabricación")]
    public DateTime Fec_fabricacion { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Fecha de Ingreso:")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe ingresar la Fecha de ingreso")]
    public DateTime Fec_ingreso { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Estado(1:activo,2:inactivo):")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe ingresar la Fecha de ingreso")]
    public char Estado { get; set; } // 1:activo,2:inactivo
    //datos de auditoria
    public string usuario { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Fec_modificacion { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Fec_stamp { get; set; }
    public string programa { get; set; }

   }
```

el modelBuilder es este:

```
   modelBuilder.Entity("REQ.UI.WEB.Models.Entities.Balanza", b =>
            {
                b.Property<int>("BalanzaID")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

                b.Property<decimal>("Cap_maxima");

                b.Property<decimal>("Cap_minima");

                b.Property<string>("Cod_Balanza")
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasAnnotation("MaxLength", 20);

                b.Property<string>("Des_balanza")
                    .HasAnnotation("MaxLength", 150);

                b.Property<char>("Estado");

                b.Property<string>("Fabrica")
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasAnnotation("MaxLength", 20);

                b.Property<DateTime>("Fec_fabricacion");

                b.Property<DateTime>("Fec_ingreso");

                b.Property<DateTime?>("Fec_modificacion");

                b.Property<DateTime?>("Fec_stamp");

                b.Property<string>("Marca")
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasAnnotation("MaxLength", 20);

                b.Property<string>("Modelo")
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasAnnotation("MaxLength", 20);

                b.Property<string>("Pro_balanza")
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasAnnotation("MaxLength", 20);

                b.Property<string>("Serie")
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasAnnotation("MaxLength", 20);

                b.Property<char>("Sit_balanza");

                b.Property<char>("Tip_balanza");

                b.Property<string>("programa");

                b.Property<string>("ubicacion")
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasAnnotation("MaxLength", 20);

                b.Property<string>("usuario");

                b.HasKey("BalanzaID");

                b.ToTable("Balanza");
            });
```

En otro proyecto que tengo si me funciona normal, pero cuando cree este proyecto me sale ese error al momento de mostrarlo en View como Lista

```
   public IActionResult ListarBalanzas()
    {
        var model = balanzaAD.GetBalanzas();
        return View(model);
    }
```

Estaré atento si se necesita algún otro dato más para poder solucionar este problema. Ojo ya intente dropear la base de datos y de nuevo hacer el Update-Database para ver si ese era problema pero no lo soluciona.

Comment: Tienes definida la configuracion de la entidad mediante DataAnnotations y mediante FluentApi, no te recomiendo usar las dos cosas, usa uno u otra. Intenta borrando la configuracion de FluentApi que puede estar generando conflictos. Que version de EF usas? se me hace muy extrana la forma en que configuras MaxLength, yo lo hago asi:             entity.Property(e => e.UnaPropiedad).HasMaxLength(100);

Comment: La version que estoy usando de EF es 1,0,0